# How to create dynamic drag and drop templates?

Tags: java, html, xml, forms, jsp

I have a requirement of developing a functionality where user can dynamically define a template (labels, textboxes, labels, rows, columns, parent child relationships among above elements etc). These elements(such as combo boxes) may be bound to different database tables.

For example, the user may define a template T1 for a specific use case U1. But this template is not restricted to U1 only. It may be needed to be used in another use case U2, where it is a sub part of a bigger template.

Once the templates are defined, another user may load the templates (HTML form) and enter data into it. At a later stage, I need to reuse this data and template to generate PDF reports. Since PDF reports may sometimes need to have a different layout than the HTML form, I would need parent child relationships between elements as well.

As of now, we are achieving by generating an XML from a user interface where a user can select elements from a dropdown and specify properties. At run time, these XML are transformed to HTML using XSLT. Another XSLT is used for generating PDFs. The limitation of this scheme is that it is very tedious to incorporate any user requests (such as multiple columns, add tables into forms etc).

I was wondering how other people achieve this and is there an API/Library for doing the same ?
I have looked at HTML5 and JQuery drag and drop features, but it would require me to add everything from scratch (such as dynamically add columns,rows etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best thing to create dynamic form is using angular js.
It is very good framework for front end development

Here is the working link for 
[`angular js form`](http://selmanh.github.io/angularjs-form-builder/#/forms/create)

Sorry, I only gave example form dynamic forms here are some example for drag and drop 
[`Angular drag and drop 1`](http://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/nested)

[`Angular drag and drop 2`](http://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/simple)

[`http://angular-js.in/dragular/`](http://angular-js.in/dragular/)

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks. Had a look at the first example. Found it suitable. But is it possible to extend the same for TextBox, combos etc in addition to items(which would be labels in my case)

Comment: Yeah, definetly you can do that, All input fields can be made through this.  dynamically drag and drop form can be made easily with angular.

Answer (score 3):

There are libraries out there for dealing with databases, such as JDAL,jOOQ and many many others.

For creating forms and reports, however, Oracle does have their [Oracle Forms and Reports](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/index.html) suite. There are also alternatives, such as [OpenXava](http://www.openxava.org/ate/oracle-forms-alternative), that can also do these things (and probably better, I've worked with 10g/11 and it can be a pain sometimes). If you're more interested in using XML and other markup languages, you might like [FOXopen](http://www.foxopen.net/Features).

All of these can output to PDF and other types of documents.

Where I work, we use Oracle Forms and internally written programs to craft our reports.